# How to scale a .png?

Tags: html, css, svg, png

I'm making a website but my logo is in PNG format because it is pixel art. I'm using a CSS line `image-rendering: pixelated;` on my logo image but I haven't seen it to be reliable in some context. SVG converters make it look weird. I want to keep the pixels but make it scalable. If it helps I'll add the html and CSS of my logo.

HTML -

```
<img src="images/favicon.png" id="logo">
```

CSS -

```
#logo {
    image-rendering: pixelated;
    position: fixed;
    left: 5px;
    top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Scale a png, as in, reduce size of the image?

Comment: I mean to make the image not lose quality when scaled, like SVG. image-rendering: pixelated; in CSS kind of works but I have found problems with it.

Comment: SVG stands for Scalable Vector Graphics, which I just want .png to have the scalable part meaning not losing quality.

Comment: I know what SVG, but SVG are not PNG files AFAIK

Comment: Thats why I asked the question on how to scale png

Comment: Please clarify when `image-rendering` fails to provide the desired result by adding a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, please revise your question's title to something more specific like "How to scale a pixel-art image without antialiasing". It is safe to say that "pixel-perfect" rendering is tricky, if not impossible - especially when using CSS layout features such as flex or grid, which eventually introduce floating point pixel values while placing elements in a distributed manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't scale PNG like vectors because there is no information how to **add** more pixels.
So the image gets blurred.

But some of those new fancy AI tools claim they can *enhance* blurred images, so try those.

You will never get the same sharpness, because only a human *understands* what needs to be done, AI will just see pixels and shapes.

If your logo is suitable  to be drawn with vectors; re-creating it by hand is your only option.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try and find a way around the problem I am having with image-rendering: pixelated;.